# Replacing Ryzen Processor in Gaming PC

Tags: processor

Currently have: Processor: AMD A8-9600 Radwon R7

Motherboard: A320M PRO-VH PLUS (MS-7B07)

Graphics card: Asus GeForce GT 1030 2GB

I am looking into upgrading processor to Ryzen 7 5800X 3D

My question is if the the motherboard and graphics card would work with new processor OR if I should just upgrade whole machine?

Thanks in advance for assistance.

This seems to be the best processor for gaming PC that I have with the same socket of existing processor.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your board [is compatible](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/A320M-PRO-VH-PLUS/support#cpu) with 5000 series CPUs using the "latest Beta BIOS", which can be found [here](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/A320M-PRO-VH-PLUS/support#bios).

However, gaming performance will still be terrible unless you also upgrade your GPU.